# How do stacked cylindrical discs work as insulators when there is metal in their center?

Tags: insulation

A couple of previous questions here asked about the purpose of stacked cylindrical discs and the answers indicated they are insulators that prevent arcing.

We recently found a broken section of these and it appears the string of discs is held together by metal pieces linked through the center of the discs.

I am trying to understand how it is that the metal doesn't act as a conduit and therefore making the discs useless. Why doesn't the electricity arc to the metal pieces and continue on to the tower?

[image: The discs on a power transfer tower.][1]]

[image: A broken off piece of the]

Comment: Here is another question about these: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161213/how-do-ceramic-disk-insulators-support-the-weight-of-transmission-lines The answers claim the core is not metal.

Comment: Some "components" can look like "metal" but are not metal. "Ceramics" are really "wonderful"?

Comment: Question answered, thanks all!